# html development for android mobile

Tags: html, android, css, user-interface

how to develop HTML + CSS for android mobile.. any guidance will be great help

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do and what you've done already.

Answer (score 2):

http://mobiforge.com/starting/story/dotmobi-mobile-web-developers-guide

Answer (score 2):

You could give [sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) a try . It is a HTML5/JavaScript Framework for developing web applications for Android and iPhone. And it's available under GPL ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know, how to access or use HTML and css in Android apps, then put your HTML and css files in the /asset folder and show them in WebView. WebView is capable of showing web pages with images, css, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer an official book from Oreilly Books:

**`Building Android Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript : Making Native Apps with Standards-Based Web Tools`**

http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920010067/preview#preview

It is a great book for developing apps using web technologies for Android.